# Updating data using execute method in jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

What are the repercussions of using executeQuery rather than executeUpdate to update data in the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`executeQuery()` returns a `ResultSet`, from which you have to retrieve the int result yourself. Moreover you have to close and release the resultset yourself.

Comment: Which means that an extra effort would be required to get the updated rows.
Also would there be a performance issue angle also involved ?

Comment: @Vivek No there is no performance difference between `executeQuery()` and `executeUpdate()`. Both call underlying `execute()` function.

Comment: @djaqeel That is an implementation detail of a specific driver, you cannot guarantee that a driver executes them both in the same way.